# ScrollController not scrolling to bottom of content

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Using a `ScrollController` and `TextFormField` `FocusNode` to `scrollController.animateTo` `scrollController.position.maxSCrollExtent` I cannot achieve displaying my "submit" button at the bottom of the view when the keyboard displays to for entry into the `TextFormField` above my "submit" button.

Note I have tried with `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` set to true and false.

My `SingleChildScrollView` code snippet

```
  ScrollConfiguration(
          behavior: ScrollBehaviorHideSplash(),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[...widgets
```

My my FocusNode on focus function:

```
  void _scrollToBottom() {
    print('scrollToBottom');
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 750),
    );
  }
```

I have also tried `_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent + 400.0` just in case.

**Content display with having `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true`:**
[image]

**Where I would like the ScrollController to scroll to but have to currently manually scroll to see the button:**
[image]

Comment: This tutorial helped me: [Automatic Scroll-To-Bottom in Flutter](https://smarx.com/posts/2020/08/automatic-scroll-to-bottom-in-flutter/)

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 750),
    );
});
```

A little bit hacky but adding Timer before scroll animation solved my problem, i guess listview needs some time to add new item.

Comment: I think this is not the best solution to lazy load items in a ListView from an api, as it will continually calling the api ever 750 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a `SingleChildScrollView` and a `ListView.separated` inside of it, I passed the scroll controller to the inner listview instead of the parent scroll view (the max scroll ), the height of the view was changing based on  the appearance of the keyboard so waiting time was required.

```
Future.delayed(
  Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  () {
    scrollController.animateTo(
      scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      curve: Curves.ease,
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use a Timer, you can use [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) to run the `animateTo` after the frame is completed:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      curve: Curves.easeOut,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 750),
    );
});
```